# Handle session expired exception

Tags: spring, security

By using Spring security,When i leave my application web opened for a while then the authentification is lost and the user must login again so when i click on a button or a link in my application to complete my work this exception appear :

```
Etat HTTP 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'principal.username' of bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken]: Bean property 'principal.username' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

so i want to hide this and show a pretty page said that the user must login, because the user may not understand the message of tomcat and he may be scary by that !! Any suggestions ?

**/* EDIT */**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

        <http auto-config="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/mise_a_jour*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/recherche*" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/pages/*" filters="none" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/css/*" filters="none" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/js/*" filters="none" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/images/*" filters="none" />
            <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/failLogin" />
            <logout logout-success-url="/logoff" />
            <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        </http>



   <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property  name="expiredUrl" value="/session-expired"  />
      </beans:bean>

        <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider>
                <password-encoder hash="sha" />
                <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                    users-by-username-query="select login,password, enable from utilisateurs where login=?"
                    authorities-by-username-query="select u.login, r.role from utilisateurs u, roles r where u.id = r.id and u.login =?  " />
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>


    </beans:beans>
```

the stack trace :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sessionRegistry' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like an authentication related problem. I mean, Spring throws `AccessDeniedException` if the user is not authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a config called expired-url that you can set, something like this

```
<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property **name="expiredUrl" value="/session-expired.htm"** />
  </beans:bean>
```

More information here http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html.

Comment: Should I write this in a new file XML ?

Comment: Should be in the security context xml

Comment: should i add something else such as a class or a controller expect the xml configuration? i adedd the lines you provide above but it generate an error.

Comment: I just add your code to the xml file and this is the error : `cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'beans:property'. 
 One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/
 schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, 
 WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}' is expected.`

Comment: Looks like you need to adjust the namespaces according to what you have defined in your xml file. Can you post the entire xml file?

Comment: Sorry, I added the code into `<http></http>` that's why i had the last exeception. now i put the code in the correct place and i write the stack trace in the edited question.

Comment: Glad you got that figured out! and thanks for updating with your answer

Comment: No ! but i still have the error that i write in the question. what i figure out is the exception here in this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675393/handle-session-expired-exception/16676102?noredirect=1#comment24753219_16676102)

Comment: I suggest you read through this http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html.